# How to compare two files on line by line basis regardless of order?

Tags: python, shell, awk, diff, ksh

I have two files and I want to check if every line in that file exists. However, sometimes the order of the words after the second word in each line is different. That's ok because i am only interested in missing/additional words after the first two words/columns.

file_A:

```
    foobar A a ab c bd hd
    bar B a c jd sm sldkjn
    baz C boo abd
```

file_B:

```
    foobar A a c bd hd ab
    baz C abd boo
    bar B c a jd sm sldkjn
```

In the example above, those two files are good based on my criteria.

At first I tried

```
   $ sort -u file_A > outA
   $ sort -u file_B > outB
   $ diff outA outB
```

This way line order is not taken into account.
However, it takes into account word order in every line.

How can I disregard the order of words on each line after the second column?

Comment: @Prune The OP has a clear description of the requirements, a clear example, a specific question, and what he's tried so far. How much more could he do to make it a good question?

Comment: What should the output be if file A has 2 identical `baz C boo abd` lines and file B only has 1 of them - are the files the same or different by your criteria?

Comment: @EdMorton they should be different. :)

Comment: I'm looking for an attempt to address the problem specified.  The straw-man example specifically treats whole lines; to "ignore word order", there must be an attempt to recognize a word unit.  This is now a moot point, since the question has a good shell answer and a brute-force Python approach.

Comment: @Prune note that i mentioned the order is not important after the second word in each line (the contents only matter), so word order is not completely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for "sorted_in":

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc" }
{
    key = $1 FS $2
    $1 = $2 = ""
    split($0,f)
    for (i in f) {
        key = key FS f[i]
    }
    keys[key]
}
NR==FNR { a[key]++; next }
{ b[key]++ }
END {
    diff = 0

    for (key in keys) {
        if (a[key] > b[key]) {
            print "<", key
            diff = 1
        }
        else if (b[key] > a[key]) {
            print ">", key
            diff = 1
        }
    }

    exit diff
}
```

The per-key count and later numeric comparison is necessary to identify cases where, for example, file_A has a given key listed 2 times but file_B only has it once and so the files should, presumably be reported as different. For example:

```
$ cat file_A
foobar A a ab c bd hd
bar B a c jd sm sldkjn
baz C boo abd
baz C boo abd

$ cat file_B
foobar A a c bd hd ab
baz C abd boo
bar B c a jd sm sldkjn

$ awk -f tst.awk file_A file_B
< baz C abd boo
```

Comment: Thank you this helpful... but I still get the difference for some reason.

Comment: @Mark idk what that means. As you can see the tool behaves as it should for the given sample input. Can you give any more details? Also check you file for control-Ms at the end of lines as those can mess things up `cat -v file`.

Comment: I am getting this as the output for the awk script
````
> bar B sm sldkjn c a jd
< bar B sm sldkjn a c jd
< foobar A bd hd a ab c
> baz C abd boo
> foobar A hd ab a c bd
< baz C boo abd
````

Comment: Command used: $ awk -f tst.awk file_A file_B. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Well, that means there's differences in your files and it's showing you what those differences are. Did you run `cat -v file` to check for control-Ms?

Answer (score 1):

Python is your friend!
You may start with something like this:

```
with open(path1, 'r') as file1:
with open(path2, 'r') as file2:
    for line in file1:
        words = line.split(" ")
        for line in file2:
            for word in words:
                if word not in line:
                    doSomething()
                else:
                    doSomethingElse()
```